# Need a sed command to substitute the middle of an axpression

Tags: bash, sed

I am looking for a sed expression allowing to move :

```
expression1\expression2\expression3
```

to

```
expression1\expression3
```

and ofcourse expression2 is different in all the file in wich i need to perform the command.

For now my solution is to focuse on the two `'\'` between expression2, but i dont find the regular expression to match any word between 2 known characters.

Any idea for doing this in one shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below sed command to replace all the characters which are present within `\`(including `\`) with `\`

```
$ echo 'expression1\expression2\expression3' | sed 's~\\.*\\~\\~g'
expression1\expression3
$ echo 'expression1\expression2\expression3' | sed 's~\\[^\\]*\\~\\~g'
expression1\expression3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk:

```
s='expression1\expression2\expression3'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\"} {print $1, $3}' <<< "$s"
expression1\expression3
```

Using sed:

```
sed 's~^\([^\\]*\)\\[^\\]*\(\\.*\)$~\1\2~' <<< "$s"
expression1\expression3
```